# CUDA 7 and 10 installed, but NVCC presents only CUDA 7

Tags: cuda

The

> /usr/local/

shows folder

> cuda

and

> cuda-10.0

folder.

Also

> $ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt

shows version 10, but nvcc shows 7. Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed CUDA 10, you should change your `~/.profile` file to match this:

```
# set PATH for cuda 10.0 installation
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi
```

Log out then back in for changes to take effect.

The `nvcc` app is found in the `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin` folder, but yours is probably showing `/usr/local/cuda-7.x/bin` in your `~/.profile` file.